# Total number of edges in the graph

Tags: graphs

Consider a `directed` graph with nodes `{1,2,3...n}` and include an edge `(i,j)` whenever `i<j`.

According to me, it should be `n(n-1)/2` but the book says it's nC2(combinations).

Comment: "whenever inC2 edges" - what was this meant to say?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden: Formatting is messing things up. Let me correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try working out what n choose 2 evaluates to?

Comment: I certainly did not. Got carried away :)